# How do I know what to pass in as TargetDevice, for Powershell DeviceManagement -> Enable-Device

Tags: powershell, module, powershell-cmdlet

I installed the DeviceManagement module for Powershell, specifically for the purpose of its Enable-Device and Disable-Device functions.

But when I call either of those, it needs a TargetDevice(which makes sense, obviously).. but I can't figure out the "name" of my device(a drive in this case) for the purposes of this command.

Answer (score 0):

As with most PowerShell cmdlets, they are designed with the pipeline in mind.

Typically the best way to handle this is to first *Get* the target of your Set or Update cmdlet, and pipe it into the one that changes it:

```
$deviceName = Read-Host -Prompt 'Please enter the Name of the Device to Disable'
Get-Device | Where-Object -Property Name -Like $deviceName | Disable-Device

$deviceName = Read-Host -Prompt 'Please enter the Name of the Device to Enable'
Get-Device | Where-Object -Property Name -Like $deviceName | Enable-Device
```

This is taken directly from [Device Management PowerShell Cmdlets Sample – An introduction](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/wincat/2012/09/06/device-management-powershell-cmdlets-sample-an-introduction/).